# Using magento price rules for custom price

Tags: price, customer, tax, rules

I have a table with 2 fields: **base_price**, **customer_group_id**. Now I need to get price with TAX from the base price (without TAX) for current customer group. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Just go thru this good tutorial. 
This is suiting your need.

```
www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/catalog-price-rules
```

Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: That is not what I need. I need some method which will return me price with valid TAX (special for the customers group which is already defined)